# CreateProcess doesn't run application (nc.exe) as it should?

Tags: c, winapi, createprocess, netcat

The problem is that when i am open nc.exe from the CMD using the `nc` syntax as in the above code it works and is connecting to my server. But when i am doing so through my program (using the above code) it just open the nc.exe window but it doesn't let me run commands i just get a blank CMD window without any prompt .

```
    PROCESS_INFORMATION pi;
    STARTUPINFO si;
    memset(&si, 0, sizeof(STARTUPINFO));
    si.cb = sizeof(STARTUPINFO);

    TCHAR nc[] = TEXT("nc.exe localhost 4444");     

    CreateProcess(NULL, nc, NULL, NULL, TRUE, 0, NULL, NULL, &si, &pi);
```

should i use any other arguments to `CreateProcess` in order to make it work as it should (or as it works when i am running it manually)? i am thinking maybe the problem is somehow relate to the StdInput StdOutput thing but i am not sure on where to go from there.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You can run it via `cmd.exe` with the **/K** argument to force the DOS window to remain open, e.g.:

```
cmd.exe /K nc.exe localhost 4444
```